# Norm of a Vector equality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

As I prepare for the exam, I have encountered the following question:

[image: Questoin]

I am not very good on this Norm calculations, so your help is important.

This is where I am so far:

[image: so far]

How do I continue from here? I have proven (I guess) the equivalence, but not the inequality.
Thanks,

Alan

Comment: This is called Cauchy-Schwarz. The proof is standard.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\triangle$-inequality & CS-inequality: $LHS = ||\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iy_i||^2\leq \left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|\cdot ||y_i||\right)^2\leq RHS $